# SQL - linking using date to 'between 2 dates' logic

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

SQL - I have table `Values` with values and corresponding dates and table `Periods` with period labels and starting dates for those periods (irregular dates).

I am trying to link two tables so that each value with a corresponding date gets assigned a label relating to each period (based on date check). There is an example:

```
Periods
--------
Desc  Dates
M1    03/01/2000
M2    05/02/2000
M3    10/03/2000
...
M12   01/12/2000


Values
-------
Value_Date   Value
05/01/2000   101
01/02/2000   201

07/02/2000   301
15/02/2000   401
```

I want to get something like this:

```
Results_1
----------
Value_Date   Value  Desc
05/01/2000   101    M1
01/02/2000   201    M1
07/02/2000   301    M2
15/02/2000   401    M2

 and then 


Results_2
----------
Desc   Value_Total
M1     302
M2     702
```

What would be an efficient way to do it in Athena/Presto SQL?

Comment: I am using Athena/Presto

Comment: On a side note: You should avoid names that are SQL words (`desc`, `values`).

Answer (score 0):

You could join all periods with a start date less or equal than the value date and then dismiss all but the latest. This is probably not very efficient, but does the job.

```
select ranked.desc, sum(value) as total
from
(
  select
    v.value_date,
    v.value,
    p.desc,
    row_number() over (partition by v.value_date, v.value order by p.dates desc) as rn
  from values v
  join periods p on p.dates <= v.value_date
) ranked
where rn = 1
group by ranked.desc
order by ranked.desc;
```

(If `value_date` is unique in the `values` table, then you can remove `, v.value` from the partition clause.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEAD` to get the periods' end dates. Then joining is simple.

```
with complete_periods as
(
  select 
    p.desc,
    p.dates as start_date,
    coalesce(
      lead(p.dates) over (order by start_date) - interval '1' day,
      date '2999-12-31' -- high date, so we don't have to deal with null
    ) as end_date
  from periods p
)
select p.desc, sum(v.value) as total
from values v
join complete_periods p on v.value_date between p.start_date and p.end_date
group by p.desc
order by p.desc;
```